# Smooth minimum and smooth maximum function in math node in blender

Tags: shader-nodes

I want to learn about smooth minimum and smooth maximum function but there is no clearly defined formula out there, even in the Blender's manual which redirects to a Wikipedia page. But there it shows lots of methods and formulas I don't know which one is correct. So if there is a simple formula please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blender's smooth minimum function is [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/c8ac1280bb7e69bffadff4cf8c8f71f9c0ec6616/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_base_inline.c#L491). It is

$$\operatorname{smoothmin}(a,b,c) = \min(a,b) - {c \over 6} \left({\max(c - |a - b|, 0) \over c}\right)^3$$

(When c is zero, drop the second term.)

This is the cubic polynomial smin function from https://iquilezles.org/articles/smin/.

---

The smooth maximum just turns the max into a min by negating ([source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/c8ac1280bb7e69bffadff4cf8c8f71f9c0ec6616/source/blender/nodes/texture/nodes/node_texture_math.c#L291-L293))

$$\operatorname{smoothmax}(a,b,c) = -\operatorname{smoothmin}(-a, -b, c)$$

Comment: hey, scurest what happens when we provide the values 2, 1.3, and  9.3 for values one and two and distance respectively, because I solve this using the formula you have given but its value is negative but in blender it is near the value of 0.2 or something please help me out.

Comment: smoothmin(2, 1.3, 9.3) = 1.3 - (9.3/6)(8.6/9.3)^3 = 0.0743, which is what Blender gives.